# Check at compile time class constructor signature

Tags: c++, boost

Is there a way to check at compile time if some class has constructor with certain arguments ?
?

For example:

```
class foo {
    foo(std::string &s) {
    }
};
```

I want to check at compile time that constructor with std::string& **always** defined. Maybe boost provides such functionality ?

Comment: You mean without trying to create objects?

Comment: If you use this constructor while it's not defined, the compiler will generate an error. If you don't use it, then why do you want it to be present?

Comment: The interesting testcase for any proposed check is std::string itself.

Answer (score 7):

The common way to check if a specific function exists is to take its address and assign it to a dummy variable. This is a lot more precise than the tests mentioned so far, because this verifies the exact function signature. And the question was specifically about **`string&`** in the signature, so non-const and thus presumably modifying the string.

However, in this case you cannot use the take-the-address-and-assign-it trick: constructors don't have addresses. So, how do you check the signature then? Simply: Befriend it in a dummy class.

```
template<typename T>
class checkSignature_StringRef {
    friend T::T(string&);
};
```

This too is a very specific check: it will not even match similar constructors like `foo::foo(std::string &s, int dummy = 0)`.

Comment: That doesn't compile with VC8: class contains explicit override 'T::{ctor}' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration

Comment: note the defect report here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#215

Comment: crash on gcc3! Compile error on gcc4... That method looks good but I'd be happy to know that anybody else made it compile...

Comment: anyway, while this is certainly a very clever idea, i'm not sure how you can make use of it with SFINAE: It fails for invalid constructs in the immediate context of type-checking and invalid expressions. "External effects", such as implicit definition of a constructor that would be illformed, or (i would argue) an invalid friend declaration in an instantiated class body, won't be caught by SFINAE. Those are C++1x rules. In C++03, there is an explicit list of cases where an SFINAE failure happens, which doesn't include an invalid friend declaration.

Comment: You could use this too: sizeof(T(*(string*)0)) . I think that should cause an SFINAE failure in C++1x . But i don't think it's required to do an sfinae failure with c++03. In any case, C++1x could do that better using concepts anyway :) Read this one: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2634.html

Comment: Following http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#215: this method does work on non ctor function thought

Comment: Fair point about SFINAE, but my goal was definitely SFIAE ;)

And for compilers that trip over the templated friend, there's always the macro option: #define CHECKSIGNATURE_STRINGREF(T) namespace { class CHECKSIGNATURE_STRINGREF_TESTER { friend T::T(string&) } }; // Except that this macro will fail on qualified-id's

Comment: This answer doesn't work. If anybody can make any use of it please send compiler version and code example please.

Answer (score 5):

I came up with a similar problem wanting to forward constructors to base class when the arguments are compatible, and to do something else when not.

Here is a generalized traits working on MSVC 2013 (requires C++11 stuff):

```
namespace detail {
    template<class type,class...Args>
    class constructible_from
    {
        template<class C>
        static C arg();

        template <typename U>
        static boost::mpl::true_ constructible_test(U *, decltype( U(arg<Args>()...) ) * = 0 );
        static boost::mpl::false_ constructible_test(...);

    public:

        typedef decltype( constructible_test(static_cast<type*>(nullptr)) ) result;

    };
}   // namespace detail

template<class type>
struct constructible
{
    template<class...Args>
    struct from :
        detail::constructible_from<type,Args...>::result {};
};
```

Here is a traits usage example, I leave the *enable_if* application as an exercise :D :

```
struct b{};
struct c{};
struct d : c{};

struct a
{
    a() {}
    a(a &) {}
    a(b,c) {}
    a(c) {}
};


static_assert(
    constructible<a>::from<>::value,
    "a()"
);
static_assert(
    constructible<a>::from<a&>::value,
    "a(a&)"
);
static_assert(
    ! constructible<a>::from<const a&>::value,
    "a(const a&)"
);
static_assert(
    constructible<a>::from<b,c>::value,
    "a(b,c)"
);
static_assert(
    ! constructible<a>::from<b>::value,
    "a(b)"
);
static_assert(
    constructible<a>::from<c>::value,
    "a(c)"
);
static_assert(
    constructible<a>::from<d>::value,
    "a(d)"
);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really need it, you can add this function:

```
static void _dummy() { std::string s; foo f(s); }
```

Without your constructor, the compilation will fail. Note: your constructor is private. If it's on purpose, then _dummy should be inside the class. Otherwise, you can have it outside the class.

Also, you can templatize or even make it a macro, if this happens a lot in your code.

But to tell the truth, it still looks like a hack. Are you sure you need it?

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to check if foo is constructible from a string, you can use `boost::is_convertible`.

For example:

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((boost::is_convertible<std::string, foo>::value));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Concept check in boost 1.39:

```
#include <boost/concept_check.hpp>

class foo_c
{
public:
    foo_c(std::string& s)
    {}
};

template<typename T>
class algo_c
{
BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::Convertible<std::string,T>));
public:
    algo_c()
    {}
};
```

Removing or changing the constructor of foo_c result in the following compile time error:

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot
>   convert from 'std::string' to 'foo_c'

EDIT:
That can be made to work with explicit constructor with a homemade concept check:

```
template <typename T>
struct HasTheRightConstructor
{
    BOOST_CONCEPT_USAGE(HasTheRightConstructor)
    {
        std::string v;
        T j(v);
    }
};
```

Comment: This method does not work for explicit constructors. It works only for constructors with 1 non-default argument. It does not work, if conversion operator is defined from "std::string" to T

Comment: Good point. Edited so that it works with explicit ctor. Don't know how to do  to match a precise prototype (can't make answer from MSalters to compile

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for sounds a lot like a unit test.  I would download something like [cppunit](http://apps.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page) and integrate it into your compilation.

Any unit tests you write will be built/executed at compile time.  See [Unit Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) for more information.

Comment: Unit tests are not really at compile time, and that was very explicitly asked. There are already 2 solutions which prove that's quite possible.

Comment: Unit Tests aren't a compile time check, but they can be setup to run when you compile your code.  This gives you what you are probably looking for anyways, which is a way to validate functional contracts and assumptions about your code.  

Is there a reason why this must happen at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

If you need this kind of checks, you'll probably need some other compile time checking

I suggest to take a look to boost concept checking library (documentation is **[here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm)**). You can find some documentation, classes and macros that can help you.