# Syntax for pointers to constructors in C++

Tags: c++

I'm making a cross-platform library implementing several basic primitives on several platforms. To verify that every implementation of a primitive (i.e. class) provides core members required on all platforms I use the following construct:

```
template<typename _Ty> int _MethodVerifyHelper(_Ty);
#define ENSURE_MEMBER_DECL(className, methodName, returnType, ...) typedef char __PROTOTYPE_VERIFIER__[sizeof(_MethodVerifyHelper<returnType (className::*)(__VA_ARGS__)>(&className::methodName))]
```

Then I write something like this:

```
ENSURE_MEMBER_DECL(Event, TryWait, bool, unsigned);
```

So if the Event class has no `bool TryWait(unsigned)` method, we'll get a compilation error here.

The question is: **is there a similar syntax in C++ to declare pointers to constructors?** I want to have a statement that causes a compile-time error if a class does not provide a constructor with given argument types.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check at compile time class constructor signature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949432/check-at-compile-time-class-constructor-signature)

Comment: Off-topic, but you shouldn't use [reserved names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) like `_Ty` and `_MethodVerifyHelper`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no way you can take the address of a constructor, but you can
easily get a compile time error if an object can't be constructed with a
given set of arguments:

```
typedef int dummyToTriggerError[ sizeof( T( arg1, arg2, arg3 ) ) ];
```

The essential part is, of course, the `sizeof` expression, which
contains a construction of the object which will never be evaluated, but
which must be legal.  It's wrapped in a `typedef` to ensure that it
won't generate any code, ever.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot take a pointer to a constructor.

The way to ensure a particular constructor is provided would be to simulate a call to the constructor inside a non-execution context (e.g. `sizeof`):

```
static_assert(sizeof(className(std::declval<arg1_type>(), std::declval<arg2_type>())) > 0, "");
```