# Static Assert that a type A can be constructed from type B

Tags: c++, boost, sfinae, type-traits, c++-concepts

I am trying to to do a static assertion to check that for two types A and B; class A should have a public constructor of signature A(B& b) or A(const B& b).

I would like to have something of sort of `is_constructable_from<A, B>::value` which evaluates to `true` if there exists a public A(B& b) or A(const B& b) or A(B b).

I guess this is somewhat different than boost [is_convertible type_trait](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_convertible.html).

How do I achieve this?

Have I missed something which will do this in Boost Type Traits or Concept Check library?

Right now I need this to do a static check that the expression `A a(b)` is a valid one, which as suggested by Sehe is a less restrictive than the previous concept. A solution for both the cases are welcome. I am allowed to use Boost.

Comment: Your "in other words" description describes a /different/ requirement! (implicit conversions and bound temporaries...)

Comment: Pardon my newbie c++ knowledge, but I didn't understand the temporary part of your comment. For now I will be happy with the 2nd description than the more strict 1st description.

Comment: If your ctor takes a `const&` or a value it can accept the result of implicit conversions (temporaries).

Comment: Okay, I updated my question. I would like to know the solution for both this concept checks.

Comment: Explain why `is_convertible_type_trait` won't work for you?

Comment: Stuff like `is_convertible<int* const, int*>::value` which is always true is not a concept that I want A and B to model. Basically is_convertible type trait is much less restrictive than what I would like my `is_constructable_from` to be.

Comment: Hm...then what about `is_convertible_type_trait` and both A and B are class types?

Comment: I think if class A has a constructor `A(B)` then `is_convertible<A,B>::value` will be `true`, but I would like to do a more stricter concept check.

Comment: Off the top of my head, if you can convert from B to A, then there is either A(B), A(B &), A(const B &), A(B&&), A(const B &&), or conversion operator(s) like: B::operator A(). So it's not clear to me what you want to disallow.

Comment: I guess you are right. I am using that as of now, but I was not able to understand the complex [code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp) so I don't know how much should I trust it. Is there a way to write this with boost::concept_check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors are not member functions - they don’t have an address that you can take, so it is impossible to test for their presence in a straightforward way with SFINAE<sup>*</sup>.

While it isn't *exactly* what you asked for, with C++11 you can get close with **[std::is_constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible)**,
and with C++03 you have to rollout your own:

```
template<class A, class B = void>
struct is_constructible;

template<class A, class B>
struct is_constructible { 

    template<class U> static U declval();    
    template<std::size_t N> struct dummy;
    template<class U> static char test(dummy<sizeof(U(declval<B>()))>*);        
    template<class U> static long test(...);

    static const bool value = sizeof(test<A>(0)) == sizeof(char); 
};
```

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> The following is an interesting attempt, but to the best of my understanding it doesn't work well across compilers:

 [Check at compile time class constructor signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949432/check-at-compile-time-class-constructor-signature)</sub>