# Automatic selection of constructor based on available overloaded versions in Abstract Factory

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I am writing an Abstract Factory using C++ templates and was hit by a small obstacle.  Namely, a generic class T may provide one or more of the following ways to construct objects:

```
static T* T::create(int arg);
T(int arg);
T();
```

I am writing the abstract factory class so that it can automatically try these three potential constructions in the given order:

```
template <class T>
class Factory {
public:
    T* create(int arg) {
        return T::create(arg);  // first preference
        return new T(arg);  // this if above does not exist
        return new T;  // this if above does not exist
        // compiler error if none of the three is provided by class T
    }
};
```

How do I achieve this with C++ template?  Thank you.

Comment: This is possible but the answer (code) is not quite trivial. I solve such problems by [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) if I _must_. But before I do this effort I consider a design where all related constructors have a unique signature.

Comment: You may google "stackoverflow C++ SFINAE" to find some similar questions (and answers).

Comment: BTW, better to return `unique_ptr` than owning raw pointer.

Comment: @Scheff I tried searching but there are so many noise in the results that I couldn't find what I want.  I agree that a uniform signature is best, but unfortunately in my case the existing classes were already written with different interfaces, so I am actually trying to make them uniform with abstract factory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along this line should work:

```
struct S { static auto create(int) { return new S; } };
struct T { T(int) {} };
struct U {};

template<int N> struct tag: tag<N-1> {};
template<> struct tag<0> {};

class Factory {
    template<typename C>
    auto create(tag<2>, int N) -> decltype(C::create(N)) {
        return C::create(N);
    }

    template<typename C>
    auto create(tag<1>, int N) -> decltype(new C{N}) {
        return new C{N};
    }

    template<typename C>
    auto create(tag<0>, ...) {
        return new C{};
    }

public:
    template<typename C>
    auto create(int N) {
        return create<C>(tag<2>{}, N);
    }
};

int main() {
    Factory factory;
    factory.create<S>(0);
    factory.create<T>(0);
    factory.create<U>(0);
}
```

It's based on sfinae and tag dispatching techniques.
The basic idea is that you forward the `create` function of your factory to a set of internal functions. These functions test the features you are looking for in order because of the presence of `tag` and are discarded if the test fail. Because of sfinae, as long as one of them succeeds, the code compiles and everything works as expected.

---

Here is a similar solution in C++17:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct S { static auto create(int) { return new S; } };
struct T { T(int) {} };
struct U {};

template<typename C> constexpr auto has_create(int) -> decltype(C::create(std::declval<int>()), bool{}) { return true; }
template<typename C> constexpr auto has_create(char) { return false; }

struct Factory {
    template<typename C>
    auto create(int N) {
        if constexpr(has_create<C>(0)) {
            std::cout << "has create" << std::endl;
            return C::create(N);
        } else if constexpr(std::is_constructible_v<C, int>) {
            std::cout << "has proper constructor" << std::endl;
            return new C{N};
        } else {
            std::cout << "well, do it and shut up" << std::endl;
            (void)N;
            return C{};
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Factory factory;
    factory.create<S>(0);
    factory.create<T>(0);
    factory.create<U>(0);
}
```

Thanks to @StoryTeller and @Jarod42 for the help in this difficult morning.
See it up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PlB3xQ9mh77aKQl9).

Comment: Ugh... So when is C++17 rolling along? I really can't wait to be able to untangle such messes with constexpr if.

Comment: @StoryTeller Fair enough. I'm adding also the same example in C++17. Anyway it's not the most used revision yet and it's worth showing also the old plain approach. Isn't it?

Comment: You misunderstand me. I don't think the answer is lacking. I just can't wait to officially have more language support for this kind of things.

Comment: @StoryTeller Of course, I misunderstood you indeed. Actually I thought about it but I don't see how to approach it with `constexpr if`s. Any idea? My son got cold and stayed asleep the whole night. I'm not that clever today morning, I'm sorry. :-)

Comment: No worries, and a speedy recovery to your son! I think a chain of `constexpr if` over the OP's own attempt will work. First case checks the existence of `create` in some custom fashion, second `std::is_constructible`, third is up to the implementer. Should work, I think.

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh, yeah, finally I got it. Let me make an example and put it in the answer. Thank you.

Comment: `decltype(C::create(0))` might succeed with `C::Create(T*)`. `decltype(C::create(std::declval<int>()))` would solve that. Sad that `is_detected` is only in experimental :-/

Comment: I don't understand the line `(void)N;`, what does this actually do?

Comment: @Brotcrunsher suppresses a warning, nothing more. :-)

Comment: I feel embarrassed to ask, but - we are still not using even c++11 T_T is there any way of doing it without decltype?

Comment: @Pigpag Yeah, probably. A lot of code and a sfinae'd jungle should get it out of C++98. I'm not anymore in front of my laptop, I can't test it right now, but I can have a go sooner or later tomorrow morning (I'm from Italy, so consider the timezone).

Comment: I think I've got the right direction thanks to your tag dispatching idea, plus [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949432/check-at-compile-time-class-constructor-signature) for checking signatures of functions and constructors.  Should work under pre C++11 compiler now...let me try..

Comment: @StoryTeller At the risk of a ban, I still have to thank you for the words spent for my son in your comment today morning. Really appreciated. :-)

Comment: @skypjack - Ban shman. If they start banning us for acting like decent human beings, SO is officially past its time. And I do hope your son is feeling better now :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46763984/5244399) by @skypjack I was able to come up with a more compatible solution that works with pre c++11 compilers.  The core idea is the same, i.e. using tag dispatching for ordered testing. Instead of relying on decltype, I used `sizeof` and a dummy class for SFINAE.

```
struct S { static auto create(int) { return new S; } };
struct T { T(int) {} };
struct U {};

template<class C, int=sizeof(C::create(0))> struct test_1 { typedef int type; };
template<class C, int=sizeof(C(0))> struct test_2 { typedef int type; };
template<class C, int=sizeof(C())> struct test_3 { typedef int type; };

template<int N> struct priority: priority<N-1> {};
template<> struct priority<0> {};

class Factory {
    template<typename C>
    C* create(priority<2>, typename test_1<C>::type N) {
        return C::create(N);
    }

    template<typename C>
    C* create(priority<1>, typename test_2<C>::type N) {
        return new C(N);
    }

    template<typename C>
    C* create(priority<0>, typename test_3<C>::type N) {
        return new C();
    }

public:
    template<typename C>
    C* create(int N) {
        return create<C>(priority<2>(), N);
    }
};

int main() {
    Factory factory;
    factory.create<S>(0);
    factory.create<T>(0);
    factory.create<U>(0);
}
```

<s>Not sure if it is even possible to stuff the `sizeof` part into the private function signatures; if so, we can get rid of the dummy classes as well.</s>(failed)  The slightly ugly part is to use constants (`0` in this case) for `sizeof` operator, which may get tricky if the constructors take arguments of very complicated types.